# Mutate data conditionally in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to mutate data by dividing based on an identifier.
For example, I would like to mutate `mass` in the following data.  If it is depth 10, I would like to divide by 2.  If it is depth 20, I would like to divide by 3.

```
day    year    depth    mass 
1      2008    10       13
2      2008    10       15
1      2008    20       14
2      2008    20       12
1      2009    10       14
2      2009    10       16
1      2009    20       12
2      2009    20       18
```

Division leads to:

```
day    year    depth    mass 
1      2008    10      6.5
1      2008    10      6.5
2      2008    10      7.5
2      2008    10      7.5
1      2008    20      4.6
1      2008    20      4.6
2      2008    20      4
2      2008    20      4
1      2009    10      7
1      2009    10      7
2      2009    10      8
2      2009    10      8   
1      2009    20      4
1      2009    20      4  
2      2009    20      6 
2      2009    20      6
```

I am trying `ifelse` in the following way, but get an error "unused arguments(c(13, 15, 14. . .)"

```
df%>% 
  group_by(day, year, depth) %>% 
  bind_rows(., .) %>%
  mutate(mass = ifelse(depth == 10), mass/2,
         ifelse(depth == 20), mass/3)%>%
  arrange(day, year, depth, mass)
```

Comment: I just wonder why you want to make the data size double. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see two errors in your use of `ifelse`.  where you have `ifelse(depth == 10)`, you've only given `ifelse` one argument where it needs three. Remove the closing parenthesis and you have a good start.

Your second error is that you didn't give any indication of what to do if the second `ifelse` condition resolves to `FALSE`.  In the code below, I've assigned `NA` to that situation.  I'm not sure if that's the behavior you want, however, so you should change it to what fits your needs.

```
df%>% 
  group_by(day, year, depth) %>% 
  bind_rows(., .) %>%
  mutate(mass = ifelse(test = (depth == 10), 
                       yes = mass/2,
                       no = ifelse(test = (depth == 20), 
                                   yes = mass/3,
                                   no = NA))) %>%
  arrange(day, year, depth, mass)
```

Answer (score 5):

Usage:

```
ifelse(test, yes, no)
```

In your case:

```
ifelse(depth == 10, mass/2, ifelse(depth == 20, mass/3 , mass))
```

Comment: You should give some context around why your solution works to help educate.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo operator works well here.

```
df %>%
    mutate(mass = mass *
        as.integer(!(depth %% 10)) * 1 / 2 +
        as.integer(!(depth %% 20)) * 1 / 3 
    ) %>%
arrange(day, year, depth, mass)

# let underscore _ denote previous line result
# depth %% 10   ---> remainder left over after modulus division
# !(_)          ---> coerce integer to logical and negate 
# as.integer(_) ---> coerce back to integer for arithmetic operations
```